# Designing an sql query

Tags: mysql, join

Say, I have 3 tables - `purchase`, `image`, `coupons`

The fields in `purchase` table are - `purchase_id`, `image_id`, `user_id`, `purchase_time`.

The fields in `image` table are - `image_id`, `image_name`, `image_caption` and other image details.

The fields in `coupon` table are - `image_id`, `user_id` and `coupon_id`.

[Note: A single `purchase_id` has unique `image_id` and `user_id` (the person who purchased) but for `coupon` a single `image_id` can have multiple `user_id` (many people can generate coupon from the same image). ]

First, I am selecting the list of images -

```
SELECT p.purchase_id, 
       p.purchase_time, 
       p.user_id, 
       i.image_name, 
       i.image_caption 
FROM purchase p 
LEFT JOIN image i ON p.image_id = i.image_id 
WHERE p.user_id IN ($friends_id_string) 
ORDER BY p.purchase_time DESC
```

The `friends_id_string` is the list of `user_id` of all friends of a user

Next, I need the `coupon_id` for every image (the value of which can be `NULL` as well)

```
SELECT c.coupon_id 
FROM coupon c 
WHERE c.image_id = $image_id AND c.user_id = $user_id
```

So this query tells me if there is an active `coupon_id` for that user and that image.

The above queries involve querying on each image separately, which is hammering on the database. Can I join them together?

Comment: For a particular user with a `user_id`, I want all `purchase_id`, `image_id` of him and his friends (given by `$friends_id_string`), plus the `coupon id` for each `image_id` of that particular `user_id`.

Comment: can you run what is the result of the query below? it's only a derived query from yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested as you have not provided the schema, sample records and desired result but give this a try,

```
SELECT  p.purchase_id,
        p.purchase_time,
        p.user_id,
        i.image_name,
        i.image_caption,
        c.coupon_id
FROM    purchase p
        LEFT JOIN IMAGE i
            ON p.image_id = i.image_id
        LEFT JOIN coupon c
            ON c.image_id = p.image_ID AND
                c.user_id = p.user_ID
WHERE p.user_id IN ($FRIENDS_ID_STRING)
ORDER BY p.purchase_time DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, there is one problem. `LEFT JOIN coupon c ON c.image_id = p.image_ID AND c.user_id = p.user_ID` is not going to give me the result I want. I need `c.user_id = $user_id` . Here, $user_id is the user ID of the particular user and will not change throughout. I am looking for the coupons of that particular `$user_id`.

Comment: It may happen that a `coupon_id` may not exist (practical reason: user has not generated coupon yet). So, shall I need to do a `RIGHT JOIN` ?

Comment: @banskt please remove `AND
                c.user_id = p.user_ID` from the second `LEFT JOIN` and see the result. you have mentioned that *for coupon a single image_id can have multiple user_id*

Comment: I used this - `LEFT JOIN coupon c ON c.image_id = p.image_id AND c.user_id = $user_id` and is working. 

Thanks so much for your help.